# I need this title in 2 centered lines....using memoir

Tags: memoir

I need the chapter title to be in 2 centered lines....is there a way to do it?

Here is my custom MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
    \usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
    \usepackage{indentfirst} %Define identação em todo primeiro parágrafo
    \usepackage{garamondx} %Define a nova fonte garamond
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \chapterstyle{thatcher}

    \begin{document} %====================================================================
        \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\chapnumfont\HUGE\thechapter}}
        \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par\bigbreak}

    \chapter{APRESENTAÇÃO A 18 EDIÇÃO}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\\`, but you need to `\protect` it.

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{indentfirst} %Define identação em todo primeiro parágrafo
\usepackage{garamondx} %Define a nova fonte garamond
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering\chapnumfont\HUGE\thechapter}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par\bigbreak}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter
[Apresentação a 18 edição] % toc entry
[APRESENTAÇÃO]             % header
{APRESENTAÇÃO \protect\\ A 18 EDIÇÃO}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Addition

If you want this single chapter title not to be uppercased, do like

```
\protected\def\apresentacao{Apresentação \protect\\ a 18 edição}
\chapter
[Apresentação a 18 edição]
[APRESENTAÇÃO]
{\apresentacao}
```

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Worked like a charm!
Understood the `%toc` entry and the `\protect ` but where does the header shows up?

Comment: @Adriano Look at the next page

Comment: Understood, I will remove it as the author of the book I am editing did not like headers.
Thanks @egreg

Comment: Is there a way to have the title "À 18 Edição" NOT capital?
Because just by including it like this: `\chapter[Apresentação à 18ª edição] {APRESENTAÇÃO \protect\\ à 18ª Edição}` does not work.

Comment: There are more chapters in `\frontmatter` I would like to find a local solution not to affect the others.

Comment: @Adriano I guess that the `thatcher` chapter style does uppercasing

Comment: Do you mean that it is impossible to have it lowercase? I believe that maybe there are solutions that would be considered hacking.

Comment: @Adriano I added a workaround